# How can I apply CSS to a Google Maps HeatmapLayer?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

I've got a Google Maps with several heatmap layers, and would like to enable them with CSS instead of via setMap.  The main reason is to use css opacity transition effects.

**How do I add a class to the heatmap layer's div?**

I've used the snippet below as a hacky workaround, but it can be inconsistent when other layers are added and removed.

```js
$('#map .gm-style > div:eq(0) > div:eq(0) > div:eq(1) > div:eq(0)').addClass('my-heatmap')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer#customize_a_heatmap_layer) and [samples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap) in it doesn't indicate that you can apply CSS that way, though.

Customizations of `HeadmapLayer` can only be done using [`HeatmaplayerOptions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#HeatmapLayerOptions) which also specifies the properties you can use to customize it.

Comment: seems you are correct - most likely I will have to overload the HeatmapLayer and add the class name in there during its initialization through something like the `map.getPanes` function